# How to disable Gnome screencast?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

The [Gnome screencast utility](https://opensource.com/article/19/8/record-screencasts-gnome3) may be invoked by the keystroke <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

I'm delivering RHEL to an environment which frowns upon screen recording, so I need this to be disabled.

Googling the topic only turns up excited descriptions of how to grab video, or change the max length parameter. A trawl through `dconf-editor` gives no clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

**Gnome ScreenCast functionality cannot be disabled.**

@BlueManCZ provided a decent answer about masking the keyboard shortcut.

However, masking the keyboard shortcut with a blank that doesn't properly *disable* the screencast function.

It's provided by the `gnome-shell` package as a `dbus` interface, and its descriptor file is `/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.xml`.

The [`dbus-send(1)`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html) and [`gdbus(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libglib2.0-bin/gdbus.1.en.html) commands may be used to invoke the `Screencast` method using hints from that descriptor file:

```
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screencast \
> --method org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.Screencast \
> "/tmp/test_%d_%t.webm" "{'draw-cursor': <'true'>}"
$ ls -l /tmp/test*webm
-rw-r--r--. 1 rich rich 270035 Jun 25 17:16 /tmp/test_2020-06-25_17:16:29.webm
```

**It's worse**: the `gnome-shell` RPM package doesn't treat its interface descriptors as configs. This can be shown by making a minor change to the file or removing it, then verify the RPM:

```
# rpm -q --verify gnome-shell
S.5....T.    /usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.xml
```

The absence of a [`c` flag](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-output.html) here indicates that this is not treated as a config; and so will be restored the next time the package is installed (updated, downgraded, etc.)

Comment: The `dbus-send` invocation is going to take some finessing to get it to do something, but this doesn't return an error: `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell.Screencast /org/gnome/Shell/Screencast org.gnome.Shell.Screencast` - at this point, I'm calling it: **this can be called from the command line**

Comment: Someone else had the same question from the other angle: https://superuser.com/questions/1367346/how-to-start-gnome-screen-recorder-from-command-line

Comment: And this guy's _almost there_: https://askubuntu.com/questions/359587/how-to-pass-asv-arguments-to-gdbus

Comment: Got it. `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screencast --method org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.Screencast  "/tmp/test_%d_%t.webm" "{'draw-cursor': <'true'>}"` - this produces a `.webm` file at `/tmp/test_*.webm`

Comment: Well done, nice analysis here. I have one question. I'm using Gentoo Linux with Gnome shell, but Screencast in my case doesn't work and never did. There is that .xml file on its place, but when I invoke keyboard shortcut, nothing happens. When I call the command you found, it returns `(false, '')`. Do you have any idea, where the problem could be?

Comment: Thanks! On my systems the command returns `(true, '/tmp/test_2020-06-26_12:41:34.webm')` - first part seems to be the dbus equivalent to `$?` - it's saying mine succeeded, yours failed. I wonder what makes it fail, then? Maybe you're missing a `webm` codec? [And I wonder how to replicate your situation in RHEL -- that would solve my problem!]

Comment: Perhaps removing dependencies such as `gstreamer-1.0`, `gstreamer-base-1.0`, or `libpipewire-0.3` will break its functionality as hinted in the Source Code [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/tree/master/js/dbusServices/screencast),[here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/dbusServices/meson.build#L12) and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/meson.build#L103), but Gnome uses Gstreamer a lot I think, so you may break some other dependency aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Gnome settings - Devices - Keyboard Shortcuts and there you can find "Record a short screencast". Change this bind to any other shortcut or disable it.

[image]

Comment: While this is useful for obscuring the function, it's not an answer to my question, which is about _disabling_ the function. Sure, you can set a keystroke as a mandatory policy, but to make it impossible to invoke, the solution relies on the existence of an "impossible keystroke", if there even is such a thing. A major obstacle to finding such a keystroke is that, if you can enter a keystroke into policy, then you can also read back the config, and use a keymapping tool to produce that keystroke.

Comment: @Rich Well, Gnome allows you to disable that shortcut. Just click at it like you want to change shortcut and then press backspace. And if you want to uninstall it from your computer, isn't there something like a gnome-screencast package which you can remove?

Comment: It looks to be an integral component of the `gnome-shell`. Invoking it pegs one core at 100% for as long as the screencast is going on. It's invoked via a `dbus` interface, as shown by the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.xml` That's owned by the `gnome-shell` package. So long as there's a (`dbus-send`)[https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html] and an interface descriptor, this is enabled whatever the keyboard shortcut is. I suspect you wouldn't even need a Gnome Desktop to invoke it.

Comment: I appreciate the clues, but I've found the answer now.